# Python Telegram bot crashes with NoneType can't be used in 'await'

Tags: python, mongodb, telegram, pyrogram

I am using a template of Telegram management bot repo which can be found [here](https://github.com/dihanofficial/SophiaBot). The repo's RSS module is currently based on SQL, and I am trying to switch to mongodb.

So I added a new RSS module ([code](https://codeshare.io/N37RdV)).
and it's mongodb ([code](https://codeshare.io/RblpoE)).

When I try to run, it crashes with the following error:

```
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076256+00:00 app[worker.1]: 2022-01-06 16:15:43,075 - pyrogram.dispatcher - ERROR - object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076264+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076264+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/dispatcher.py", line 217, in handler_worker
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076265+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await handler.callback(self.client, *args)
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076265+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/SophiaBot/utils/errors.py", line 54, in capture
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076266+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise err
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076266+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/SophiaBot/utils/errors.py", line 32, in capture
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076267+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return await func(client, message, *args, **kwargs)
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076268+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/SophiaBot/modules/rss.py", line 124, in add_feed_func
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076268+00:00 app[worker.1]:     if await is_rss_active(chat_id):
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076268+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/SophiaBot/function/rssdb.py", line 30, in is_rss_active
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076269+00:00 app[worker.1]:     return await rssdb.find_one({"chat_id": chat_id})
2022-01-06T16:15:43.076269+00:00 app[worker.1]: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

What's the best way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try removing the `await` keyword.

```
return rssdb.find_one({"chat_id": chat_id})
```